# ${2\pi \over 3} = 2u + \sin {2u}$ (intersections of circles)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So, I was browsing the internet today, when I saw an interesting problem: Two circles, each with radii of one, are intersecting. If the area enclosed by the intersection of the two circles is equal to the area of the remaining part of one of the circles, how far apart are the circles?

After working for an hour on the problem, it came down to being able to solve the following problem:
$${2\pi \over 3} = 2u + \sin 2u$$

As far as I know, there is no practical way to express the exact solution for $u$, but am I wrong? Is there a way to solve the problem that I originally presented?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the solution as $$u\approx0.58631197033563176916623317857946935082197313438110091672573643017777071647403087$$ I fed this into the ISC, finding [no match](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc?input=0.58631197033563176916623317857946935082197313438110091672573643). So chances are *very* high that this is indeed transcendental, but that's no proof. Do you need a proof?

Comment: No, I don't *need* a proof, but a proof would be a good way to answer if there is a definite expression for the solution.

Comment: @ 2.71828-asy : Why not publishing the details of you calculus leading to your equation with unknown $u$. We cannot check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be reduced to a known transcendental equation :
$$x=\cos(x)$$
"Known" means that the result cannot be expressed on a closed form involving a finite number of standard functions. But, in theory, it could be expressed on the form of infinite series. In practice, the solving requires numerical calculus.

The result is : $x\simeq 0.739085$ and the distance between the center of the circles is $\simeq 0.807946$ (if no mistake).

[image]

Comment: @ 2.71828.asy To practically find $ \chi$ by iteration press the cos button repeatedly some 10,15 times on your hand calculator.

Comment: Wow, thanks guys! Such a nice solution.

Comment: @Narasimham I love that method of finding $\cos(x)=x$.  Its so stupidly easy to perform and it always converges (plus its fun pressing the button 10000 times)